# Find object using IBM RFT in flex application

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, automation, rft

I am facing issues while identifying objects using IBM RFT in Flex application. Objects are not being even highlighted when try to locate with 'Insert test object' functionality. I am using internet explorer. I have added my URL in 'Configure Application for testing' and added to Security tab under site. And also enabled 'Initialize and script ActiveX control....' Why additional setting do we need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it differently.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSJMXE_8.2.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/c_flex_test_process.html

> Testing Rational Functional Tester enabled Flex applications
>
> Developers can enable the Flex applications for testing by compiling
>   the Flex application with IBM Rational Functional Tester agent
>   (rft.swc for Flex 2.0, rftFlex3.0.swc and rftProp_Flex3.0.swc for Flex
>   3.0, Flex 3.2, Flex 3.3, Flex 3.4 or Flex 3.5, rftFlex4.0.swc and rftProp_Flex4.0.swc for Flex 4.0 or Flex 4.1) and Flex automation
>   framework libraries. After compilation, the developer must create an
>   HTML wrapper that embeds the enabled Flex application and provide the
>   application on a web server or on a local test computer for testing.